# Arduino function can't edit array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

**Background**

I've written an Arduino function which receives strings in the format `"a,b,c,d,e"` over a serial connection, where a,b,c,d,e are integers, and I'm trying to update an array with these integers every time a new string is received. The data is received and parsed into individual integers fine, but the array won't update properly.

**Attempt**

Below is the code, I've left the `getData()` function out as all it does is receive the string from the serial connection and store it in an array of characters `input` (that part is working fine).

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    getData();
    if(parsed == false){
        parseData(readings);
    }
}

void parseData(int readings[]) {
    x = 0;
    char * split;
    split = strtok(input,",");
    while (split != NULL)
    {
        readings[x] = split;
        split = strtok (NULL, ",");
        x++;
    }
    parsed = true;
}
```

**Problem**

If I send a string like `"6,7,8,9,0"`, the array `readings[]` is updated to `[289,291,293,295,297]` no matter what values I send, I have checked what values `split` takes inside the function and they are correct, however the line `readings[x] = split;` fails to update the array elements to anything other than those 5 numbers in that order. This is the case when the value of `readings[n]` is checked inside or outside the `parseData` function.

Also, if I send fewer than 5 integers in the string, e.g. `a,b,c`, only the first array elements will change and the others will remain at 0, e.g. `[289,291,293,0,0]`

Before I found out about passing array pointers to functions, the exact same thing was happening with slightly different code - when I called the function in the loop, I just used `parseData();`, and when I defined the function I just used `void parseData(){`

**Question**

Why isn't the array updating properly and how can I fix it?

Comment: where is `readings` and `input` declared?

Comment: `readings[x] = split;` <- `split` is a pointer.

Comment: @P0W oops I missed that - they are declared as global variables at the start `int readings[5];` and `char input[64];`, as well as `boolean parsed = true;`

Comment: @AlexF I just tried that, thanks, but now I'm just getting different incorrect values in the array `[49,50,51,52,53]` - what does the `*` do - I've only ever used C++ at a basic level with Arduino before and have never seen it properly explained in tutorials or demos that use it?

Comment: @user253751 I'm not too C++ savvy but as I understand it `split` is a pointer to the `strtok` output? However when I `Serial.print(split)`, the correct value is output to the serial monitor, and I don't understand why it can't be assigned to the array element correctly?

Comment: @S.Dunnim When you `Serial.print(char pointer)` it treats the pointer as a pointer to the start of a string, and it prints the string. The pointer is stored in the array incorrectly because it's an integer array, not a pointer array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readings` is an array of integers.
And `split` is a pointer-to-char.

The statement

```
readings[x] = split
```

stores split, which is the address of a character, as an integer value.

If I write

```
const char *pointer = "42";
int address = pointer;
```

I am *not* storing the integer value `42` in `address` - I'm storing the number identifying the memory location of the first character in my string.

If you want to convert a string into an integer, you need to parse it with a function like [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: Thank you, I've ended up using `atoi` as it is simpler. Should've realised I was trying to store a `char` in an `int` array!

Comment: @S.Dunnim actually a `char*` in an `int` array.